# How to commit a single staged file?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have staged two files `file1.js` and `file2.js` but I only want to commit `file2.js`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution: unstage the other (git status tells you how, `git reset`).

Comment: Yes this is what I did. Will accept this answer in 10 mins (since I cant do it now)

Comment: This is not always ideal. What if I've carefully staged a bunch of changes and I don't want to lose track of which files were staged?

Answer (score 30):

No need to unstage `file1.js` (assuming you want to keep the changes in this file staged for the next commit), just enter

```
git commit file2.js
```

to only commit the changes recorded in `file2.js`.

Comment: This is the shortest way. It's worth mentioning as well, here, that `git commit file2.js` means `git commit --only file2.js`. There is a `git commit --include <path>` that means "commit whatever is in the current index *plus* `<path>`", or roughly the same as `git add <path>; git commit`. ("Roughly" because the internal behavior is different, and the final state if you abort the commit is different.)

Comment: I have version 2.5.3 and `git commit file2.js` will stage the file as well as commit it.  Has this changed?

Answer (score 1):

`Reset/Unstage` the file that you don't want to commit using

```
git reset HEAD file1.js
```

After this you only have one staged file that will go into your commit.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was

`git reset file1.js` to unstage it. Then I commited `file2.js` like i normally do.

Comment: This has been mentioned in other answers already, please do not add a duplicate answer.