# Git - commit selected files

Tags: git

Let's assume that I have three files in my git repository. First I add file A to subdirectory:

```
git mv A.txt someDirectory/
```

That change is automatically added to the staging area.
Then I modify file B and C and add them to the staging area:

```
git add B.txt
git add C.txt
```

I want to perform two commits and pushes to remote, first for files B and C, second for file A which has now location. How to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git how to commit a single staged files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913384/git-how-to-commit-a-single-staged-files)

Answer (score 1):

After you have added files B and C to staging area, you can perform the first `git commit`.

Then you can use `git add` for someDirectory, and perform second `git commit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you not staged file A.txt till now, commit B.txt and C.txt first. Then stage A.txt and make a new commit for this file.

But if you have already staged A.txt, then `git reset HEAD -- <file>` will unstage file A.txt, commit B.txt and C.txt and add A.txt again to commit.

Answer (score -3):

The problem of committing to the same branch (or branching from the same head) is that if there is a problem in one pull request, we cannot merge the pull requests after that since the commits exists in all the later pull requests. My suggestion is to create a branch for every new commit:

To do so you should first set the upstream in your system (only once)
git remote add upstream https://github.com/YOUR_REPOSITORY
make sure your origin is set to your own fork:

```
git remote -v
```

origin should be set to https://github.com/YOUR_REPOSITORY
after that for each new fix do the following:

1. `git checkout -b  <new branch related to pull request>`
2. `git fetch upstream`
3. `git reset --hard upstream/development`
4. commit to origin
5. make pull request
6. go to 1 for the next issue to fix

Comment: Have you ever read the question? This does not seem to answer it at all.